# Web service for PDF generation

Tags: web-services, pdf, rest, pdf-generation

Does anybody know where I can find a Public Restful Web Service for PDF Generation? If so, do you have any experience using it (is it reliable/fast etc if commercial)?

The service needs to be able to take in any number of formats and return a PDF document.

**EDIT:** Please refrain from commenting or answering unless you know what a RESTful web service is and does.  The comment war below was due mostly to my assumption that this was generally obvious to present-day programmers.

Comment: Question is too vague. Please add more detail.

Comment: Please specify what you'd want for a response. Right now, "Yes" is the answer for your question.

Comment: Downvoters need to justify their issue/confusion- A RESTful web service for generating PDFs is explicit and understandable if you understand what RESTful webservices means.

Comment: Based on your question, I could answer Yes I am familar with a Rest service which generates PDF's. I wrote one. That answer isn't very helpful but it answers your question. What would you like to know. What do you need? What technologies....are you looking for one where you can upload docs and it converts etc etc...

Comment: @JoshBerke- I need a public one that can take any manner of args: html, text, or url to another page. So far have not found any.

Comment: @Yarin The thing is, someone answering "Yes" wouldn't know what to share. You want how it works? How the API is used?

Comment: I agree with some of the commenters - as in the answer is "Yes".  What's your technology preference?

Comment: @funktku- Just the address of the service!  RESTful Webservices should be inspectable on their own.

Comment: Rather than have a war over what implies "please share your links" (in the UK @Yarin's question would be thus interpreted) I've edited the question to ask explicitly for a) the location of a web service and b) thoughts on using it. @Yarin if you're not happy with it, edit the question. Especially edit in the details you've put in the comments.

Comment: @Ninefingers- thanks, I was seeing double...

Comment: @Yarin: They could be tech specific if your looking to build one or looking to consume one. Your original question simply stated: "Is anyone familiar with a RESTful web service for PDF generation?". I think with the edits that have been made it is no longer a vague question.

Comment: @Yarin, as this is a site for programmers, I think people were justifiably confused by your question. The assumption by some (including me) is that you were asking for details or an example you could use in how to *program* one.

Comment: @bmb- respectfully disagree on your last point- Webservices are no different than APIs as a tool programmers use- They are consumed by programs, not end users.

Comment: @Yarin, point taken. Comment edited.

Comment: @Yarin - I understand that.  I thought you might have been looking for possible implementation details.  I thought your response was a little harsh given how vague your question was when first asked.

Comment: @revdrjrr- You're right, was getting frustrated.  Removed my response

Comment: @Close voters- Please justify- we've edited to clarify and deal with stated confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one: [pdflayer API](https://pdflayer.com/)

I've also created my own in the past, using Sun's Star Office Server (now [Oracle Open Office Server](https://shop.oracle.com/pls/ostore/f?p=ostore:product:2540790703852327::::P3_PPI,P3_LPI,P3_METRIC,P3_TERM:3710059117011641485311,3760872245541631755674,Processor,_Perpetual), I think).  The pricing is ridiculous, of course.

Comment: Yeah, the question seemed pretty clear to me, but hey.

Comment: This website seems dead. Is there alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Not REST specific, but if you want to convert html documents or strings to pdf, please note that complex css-based formatting rules can be problematic in places.

Maybe some experts can bet it right, but that was my experience a few years ago.